# Having issues running RSpec - what am I missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to run a test a program using Rspec but am having some issues running the code. I'm a programming beginner so I appreciate the advice :)

The Rspec test is:

```
Require '09_timer'
describe "Timer" do
  before(:each) do
    @timer = Timer.new
  end

  it "should initialize to 0 seconds" do
    expect(@timer.seconds).to eq(0)
  end

  describe "time_string" do
    it "should display 0 seconds as 00:00:00" do
      @timer.seconds = 0
      expect(@timer.time_string).to eq("00:00:00")
    end
```

The Ruby code is:

```
class Timer
  def seconds 
    0
  end

  def time_string
    "00:00:00" 
  end   
end
```

Can anyone advise?

When I run, I receive an:
`` undefined method `seconds=' for #<Timer:0x00000001b671b8> `` error

Answer (score 2):

The problem doesn't have anything to do with RSpec. The problem is here:

```
@timer.seconds = 0
```

This doesn't mean anything to the class you've defined. You haven't told the class what `seconds =` means, so you get the error `` undefined method `seconds=' ``.

In your class, you do have a method named `seconds`:

```
def seconds 
  0
end
```

...but all this method does is return `0` when you call `@timer.seconds`. It doesn't do anything else.

If you want to be able to call `@timer.seconds = x`, you need to define a way to do that in your class. One way is to define a `seconds=` method:

```
class Timer
  def seconds=(num)
    @seconds = num
  end
  # ...
end
```

With this method, when you call `@timer.seconds = 3`, you're actually calling the method `seconds=` with the argument `3`, and the `seconds=` method assigns `3` to the instance variable `@seconds` (since you need somewhere to store the value inside the instance of your class).

This is so common in Ruby that there's a shortcut for it, the class method `attr_writer` ("attr" is short for "attribute"), which you use like this:

```
class Timer
  attr_writer :seconds
  # ...
end
```

All this does is create a `seconds=` method for us, just like the code above.

But now that we've stored a value in the `@seconds` instance variable, how do we get it back out? If we want `@timer.seconds` to return `3` (the value we called `seconds=` with), we need the `seconds` method return the value of the `@seconds` instance variable. That's easy:

```
class Timer
  attr_writer :seconds # (from above)

  def seconds
    @seconds
  end
  # ...
end
```

Now we can store a value with `seconds=` and get it back with `seconds`:

```
@timer = Timer.new
@timer.seconds = 60
puts @timer.seconds
# => 60
```

But as you maybe already guessed, we have a shortcut for this, too—the `attr_reader` class method:

```
class Timer
  attr_writer :seconds
  attr_reader :seconds
  # ...
end
```

But we have one more shortcut—if we have an `attr_reader` and `attr_writer` with the same name, we can do both with the class method `attr_accessor`:

```
class Timer
  attr_accessor :seconds
  # ...
end

@timer = Timer.new
@timer.seconds = 5
puts @timer.seconds
# => 5
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful and clear explanation. Was able to get the program working. Thanks so much